# Playing a Custom Haptic Pattern from a File

Tags: ios, swift, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to play a custom haptic pattern from a `.wav` file. The apple docs specify that:

`AHAP files are JSON-compliant dictionary representations of haptic and audio patterns that you can compose in a text editor, or any program that exports content in the JSON format.`

I'm wondering how to generate that JSON file from the original audio file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magical mapping between a WAV file and a haptic pattern. You'll just have to use your ears and your brain. Listen to the WAV file and write the haptic pattern in such a way as to imitate it.

Comment: There isn't even a way to convert an CHHapticPattern.Key based dictionary to an AHAP json file.